# How to check if previous return is the current one?

Tags: c++, function

I have the following code:

*EDIT*

`....int l=0`

```
char* FantasiaGameUtils::GetCurrentTask(char *chat_arg)
{ // I know the code looks disgusting but please ignore that as I am only testing now
    static char *szTemp1="";
    for(int i=0; i<loop; i++)
    {
        if(task[i][0]!=0)
        {
            sif (l==0) 
            {strcpy(chat_arg, task[i]);
            }
        else
            {strcpy(chat_arg, task[i+1]);
            }
        strcpy(task[i], "");

        if (szTemp1!="")
        {
            MessageBox(0, szTemp1, "szTemp Value", 0);
            MessageBox(0, chat_arg, "Initial Value", 0);
            return chat_arg != szTemp1 ? chat_arg : NULL;
        } else {
            l++;
            szTemp1 = chat_arg;
            MessageBox(0, szTemp1, "szTemp1 Value", 0); // @execute 
            return chat_arg;
        }
        }
        strcpy(chat_arg, "");
    }
    return false;
}
```

*EDIT*

What I am trying to do is make the return sequence check the previous returned value, and if its not the same as the current one, then return the current value `chat_arg`, if it is, return NULL.

The purpose of this function is to get the users prompt from the global_chat. An example of a prompt would be `!create <game-type> <game-time> <max-players>`

This prompt would be individually stored by each word enter (after each space) into the task[][] array, respectively.

From there, this function goes into play. It should copy the current task value (the current word) into the chat_arg variable.

The problem I am experiencing is, for some reason every in my main game loop. The value of chat_arg is kept through-out the game loop. I want to clear this value. I've come up with this method of which I will check if the current value in the function is the same as the previous one and if it is, return NULL (clearing the value), if it's not, then there is no reason to clear the previous value so return the current value.

Might anyone have a better or improved way I can perform this check? Or can anyone PLEASE tell me how I can get the previous returned value from memory and check it against the current value? Thank-you!

Comment: 1) you are mixing C and C++ 2) if you want your function to remember the previous return value, declare it in the function as a static variable: it will retain its previous value between function calls.

Comment: Pass in a state variable to save the previous answer or use a `static variable.

Comment: I added in the edits to the question... Now the static variable doesn't output the previous returned value, it outputs the value of task[i][0] just like chat_arg ... whys that? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you `return false` from a function which is declared to return `char *`? And you'll need a static *array* (or dynamically allocated equivalent) and `strcpy()` the value into it, since who knows what your pointer might end up pointing to, otherwise.

Comment: Why do you store the current state in the class as a member?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `C++` tag to your post, because it is not a pure `C` code.

```
for(int i=0; i < loop; i++) // This line will not compile using C compilers.
```

2) Better return `0` in below line. `false` does not match to `char*` you expect.

```
return false; -> return 0;
```

My solutions for your problem:

1) Create global variable and your local `chat_arg` compare to it.

```
extern char* g_prev_chat_arg = 0;

...

char* FantasiaGameUtils::GetCurrentTask(char *chat_arg)
{
...
    //return chat_arg != /*previous return value*/ ? chat_arg : NULL;
    if (0 == strcmp(chat_arg, g_prev_chat_arg))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        g_prev_chat_arg = chat_arg;
        return chat_arg;
    }
...
}
```

2) Create local `static` variable within your function `char* FantasiaGameUtils::GetCurrentTask(char *chat_arg)`and use it like above,

3) Store somewhere in code last returned value from `char* FantasiaGameUtils::GetCurrentTask(char *chat_arg)` and then pass it each time when you are calling `GetCurrentTask(...)`

```
char* FantasiaGameUtils::GetCurrentTask(const char* prev_chat_arg, char* chat_arg)
```

Comment: Your Point 1 is wrong. The first `for` loop is possible in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

Comment: Solutions 1 and 2 are also probably sub-optimal. Chances are high that whatever is calling `GetCurrentTask()` is re-using the memory `chat_arg` points to, so stored references to it are probably going to be unhelpful. As for point 1, @BasileStarynkevitch is obviously correct, but the use of classes is a slightly more obvious problem with calling this C code.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i < loop; i++)` _will_ compiler for up-to-date C compilers of the last 15 years.